# Downloading Image locally from GitHub Raw link using fs.writeFileSync() JS

Tags: javascript, github, fetch, fs

Currently trying to download image from GitHub locally. Everything seems to work, the fetch goes through with a `200 OK` response, however, I don't understand how to store image itself:

```
const rawGitLink = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/master/CIP-0001/CIP_Flow.png" 

const folder = "/Folder"
const imageName = "/Test"
const imageResponse = await axios.get(rawGitLink)


 fs.writeFileSync(___dirname + folder + imageName, imageResponse, (err) => {
   //Error handling                    
 }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four problems had to be fixed:

- Image name must include png format for this case
- The response must be in the correct format as a buffer for an image
- You must write the response data and not the object itself
- `__dirname` only needs two underscores

```js
const rawGitLink = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/master/CIP-0001/CIP_Flow.png"

const folder = "/Folder"
const imageName = "/Test.png"
const imageResponse = await axios.get(rawGitLink, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });

fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + folder + imageName, imageResponse.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Axios returns a special object: https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

```
let {data} = await axios.get(...)
await fs.writeFile(filename, data) // you can use fs.promises instead of sync
```

As @Leau said you should include the extension on the filename
Another sugestion is to use the `path` module to create the filename:

```
filename = path.join(__dirname, "/Folder", "Test.png")
```